# Java read pasted input from consol and then stop

Tags: java, input

I'm currently trying to solve following problem on onlinge judge: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=310.

I wonder how to determine when the program should exit, in other words when I should stop the input loop and exit the program?

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    //Something here

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(?) //How do I determine when to end?
    {
        //Doing my calculation
    }
}
```

My only idea is to make the input reader stop when all input has been pasted in the console, but I've no idea how I will do that.

Comment: why do you want to use a loop? you have to read 3 Numbers. Simply read the numbers with in.nextLine() and then compute the result

Comment: From my small experience with Online Judge the inputs they use may not be the same as the one in the description, but I will try break after 3 and see what I get for answer

Comment: I tried to set the loop to only loop 3 times which gave me wrong answer. In other words they may expect more inputs to be calculated.

Comment: Why looping? You just need to read 3 integers using `in.nextInt()`, you don't need a loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this would help:
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/data/p100.java.html

its a sample Java code from Online Judge, you can customize void Begin() and do your calculation there

Comment: This was solved by using the same way they'r using in their sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Your input: \n");
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    while(in.hasNextLine()) 
    {
       list.add(in.nextLine());
        if(list.size()==5){ //this will break the loop when list size=5
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

You have to use a trick like above to break the while loop. otherwise while loop keep running continuously.

My input:

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

Out put:

```
[hi, hi, hi, hi, hi]
```

Comment: when using scanner, i would use `nextLine()` and `hasNextLine()` OR `next()` and `hasNext()` but i wouldnt mix these together, it can give you empty strings on end of line etc.

Comment: But this solution requires that I know the number of sets of inputs, It's not the exact thing Im looking for. Or maybe I'm missing something in the problem description in the link I posted

Answer (score 0):

decide an input which is a breaking condition. e.g "EXIT"
then

```
  if(in.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")){
     break;
  }
```

Or, if not possible,like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {   
  //Something here
  int i = 0
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(in.hasNext()) //How do I determine when to end?
  {
    //code
    i++;
    if(i==3){

     //Doing my calculation
     break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wont work since my code will be run by Online Judges computers. If you look at the link below you will se the only type of input that is allowed and the expected output. http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=310

Answer (score 0):

if the input is `System.in` I would do this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int r, b, p, m;

while (true) {
    b = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    p = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    m = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

    r = doYourWoodooMagic(b, p, m);

    System.out.println(r);

    s.nextLine(); //devour that empty line between entries
}
```

So one question: why "devour" that empty line AFTER printing r? easy answer: after the last set of three numbers, there probably will not be any lines at all, so `s.nextLine();` will get stuck forever.

I dont know about UVa Online Judge, but i made similar program that terminated your program after getting the right output, so this solution would be fine, but again, i dont know how UVa Online Judge works.

IF THAT DOESNT WORK

If Judge is still giving you error, replace `s.nextLine();` with little more sophisticated code:

```
while (true) {
    // ...

    if(s.hasNextLine()) {
        s.nextLine(); //devour that empty line between entries
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

This however expects input to end with last number, if there is one more empty line after the last number you must

```
while (true) {
    // ...

    s.nextLine(); //devour that empty line between entries
    if(!s.hasNextLine()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

to eat that last empty line

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when solving a question online. I found a way to do using List and while() loop.

```
Input - 

1
4
1 2 3 4
```

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class input {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(sc.hasNext()){
           list.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    
    }
}
```

```
Output - 

[1, 4, 1 2 3 4]
```